# ¿Como pasar un parametro en una consulta en reporting Services?

Tags: mysql, ssrs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo en la anterior imagen una consulta a la cual quiero pasarle un valor que obtengo por parametro el problema está que a la hora de aceptar este cambio me arroja un error de sintaxis del Mysql (Tengo conectado el reporting services a Mysql por ODBC) ¿hay alguna manera de que yo pueda pasarle los valores que tengo por parametro a esa consulta?

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis de reporting services y Mysql no es tan compatible como lo es SQL server con reporting services, para poder añadir un condiciones como la que planteo en la pregunta con mysql se debe añadir filtros, es decir dejar la query sin ninguna condición

```
Select * from Usuarios
```

Y dentro del conjunto de datos a editar habrá una opción de filtro que nos permite filtrar la consulta dependiendo  de la columna que deseemos filtrar, hay diferentes tipos de operadores en mi caso yo escogí el operador `=` porque es el que requiero y reemplaza bien el `Where` en Mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que asegurarnos también de que el tipo de dato del parametro sea el mismo tipo de dato de la columna porque al filtrar este tiene en cuenta su tipo de dato, en caso dado de que los tipos de datos sea diferentes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la opción de parametros podremos editar el tipo de dato de nuestro parametro y darle el tipo de dato que necesitamos.
De esta manera pude resolver mi problema